# Open graph: delete action after post

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have finished coding an app, and also set up some action + object.

Do I need create a tool so that a user could delete their posted action on my right website or they can delete on their wall?

Answer (score 1):

You are not force to but in term of clarity I would add one. Look at what are doing other sites.

https://developers.intern.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/02/15/early-success-stories--timeline-apps-and-open-graph/